# How to select a distant parent from a child (button element) nested deep inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select the form element which is the distant parent of a button. The button is deeply nested inside of a div. I have two type of forms in two pages so I'm using the same event for both of them. That's why I'm using bother the selectors separated by a comma.

```js
$('.createForm, .editForm').on('click', '.delete-btn', function() {
  console.log($(this))
});
```

```css
.delete-btn{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/submit" method="POST" class="editForm">

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="d-flex ">
      ....some elements
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    ....some elements
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    ....some elements
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <div></div>

      <div>
        <div class="post-container">
          <textarea></textarea>
          <button type="button" class="delete-btn">Test</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

What I tried so far:

```
1. console.log( $( this ).parent() );
2. console.log( $( this ).parent( 'form' ) );

3. console.log( $( this ).parents() );
4. console.log( $( this ).parents( 'form' ) );

5. console.log( $( this ).parentsUntil() );
6. console.log( $( this ).parentsUntil( 'form' ) );

7. console.log( $( this ).parent().parent().parent().parent() );

8. console.log( $( this ).closest( 'form' ) );
```

Please note that the same jQuery code works when I use an input element instead of a button. Although the input element is one level out of a div than the button.

Comment: Do you mean that the forms are in different pages ?

Comment: Yes. I didn't want to use the same delete functionality twice that why used it together

Comment: What if you just find it like $('body .editForm') ?

Comment: Okay let me explain what I am trying to do. I have two forms, ```createForm and editForm``` in two different pages. They both have a button ```delete-btn``` which have the same functionality in both the forms. That's why I'm using both the form's selectors. But the issue is I need to do a special thing in editForm after clicking the delete button. which I don't want in create form. That's why I want to select the button's parent, which is the form element. And check if it has editForm class. If it does then do the special thing.

Comment: Doing the same thing with an input field and it works perfectly.

Comment: ```$( this )[ 0 ].form.classList[ 1 ] === 'editForm'``` this is the code I'm using for the input field. In the code ```this``` keyword is the input field.

Comment: have you tried something like this $(this).parents().find(function(parent) { return parent.tagName === 'form'})

Comment: @Dani Hey I just tried the last one with .find and it doesn't work. However I gave your previous one a try. Although I had to add ```.hasClass``` and made it to ```$('body form).hasClass('.editForm')```.  And it seemd to be working. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct working code

```
$('body form').hasClass('.editForm')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to find the form tag that envelops the clickable item? If so, use [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('.createForm, .editForm').on('click', '.delete-btn', function() {
  let form_tag = $(this).closest('form')
});
```

Comment: I tried that already. I get this ```S.fn.init [prevObject: S.fn.init(1)]```